# Feature Improvement-Proper suggestions while asking question?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, related-questions

When we click on Ask Question button and try to type something in title, we get similar questions asked but many times these suggestions are not relevant.

Please filter unnecessary words from question title such as what, where, when, is, was etc. and only consider more relevant words.

Comment: That might work... I imagine that the SE developers have thought about this already, and/or it's been awhile since they've worked on it.  Keep in mind that a few words in a title are not very much to go on, and people often put terrible titles in there anyway.

Comment: I don't think it was always that way. I [recently asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174998/158605) about the Related Questions search results not being very related (which got fixed), so perhaps whatever change they made which broke that search query broke this as well.